# Preventing access to fonts with .htaccess

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, font-face

My client ask me to use an especial font with @font-face on his website. But, that font is an asset to his organization, and he's afraid people would steal it. So, is there any way to make that .ttf file accesible by the browser, but prevent direct access (right now, you can read the url within the .css file, and download the font with any browser).

I know there's no absolute solution, and the font would still be available for someone with the right skills set. But I just want to make it harder to steal for the non-experts.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

**How I solved this?**

Reading [this](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web/). Typekit's team did a GREAT job on this one. It's really impossible to prevent the robery, but you can make it hard. I did two things:

1. With FontSquirrel Generator, I
   removed all the desktop glyphs,
   making the font unusable on a
   desktop.
2. Encode with Base64 all my TTF directly on my CSS
   file. (ie. src:
   url(data:font;base64,jdslajdsaljdlsajdsa))
3. EOT fonts, for IE, can't be
   converted to Base64. But, you can
   load those vía a php script that
   checks the referer, and prevent the
   direct access.

You still can reassemble the font having the base64, and yes, you can fake the referer and download the .EOT. But it would take someone with the right skills-set. People who steals fonts are regulary designer who doesn't know how to trick apache.

Comment: No expert on the matter, but I believe you have to allow access to the font. Otherwise, how would the browser use it to render on the page?

Answer (score 4):

This is completely impossible.

Instead, consider using an image, or removing unused characters from the font.

Answer (score 4):

If you let something to get to the browser then its public. AFAIK there is no way to block the stuff that you let browser read it!

Edit this bit of code and you can make image of text with font you want (it need GD library):

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(145, 30);// Image size
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 163, 197, 82);// color
$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
imagecolortransparent($image, $bg);// Makes Background transparent!
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$bg);
imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 25, 25, $color, "add/to/font.ttf", "text you can get from post or somewhere");
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Comment: This website has a lot of places using the font. The navigation bar, and every title. It would be heavy on the server to render 50 images with php on every page load. Although, I could make a cache folder to prevent this. The thing that would be a harsh, is that images are not readable by search bots. That's why I prefer to use text. Thanks for your suggestions any way!

Comment: Your welcome and for search bots "alt" attribute is handy, and you can add some css to make it look the same size and color of the Text In image so the user will have everything before the images load and ofcourse the search bots too !

Answer (score 2):

Create a CGI script named .ttf.  Add `AddHandler cgi-script ttf` to the Apache options for this directory (in httpd.conf or .htaccess).

Have the CGI script check the `Referer` field (yes, it's spelled incorrectly like that in the spec) and compare it against the address you expect it to be coming from.  If it is, open the font file and write it (prepended by a couple of HTTP headers, of course).  If not, redirect somewhere else.

I never checked the `Referer` field, but I did something sort of similar with PDFs a long time ago.

Note: if I wanted to get the font, this would only slow me down a little.  But it would slow most people down a lot.  I recommend making an image file with your text and putting it in your website.

Comment: This looks like an interesting option. But I've never ever wrote CGI scripts. Do you think something like this would work http://www.mail-archive.com/beginners-cgi@perl.org/msg05035.html ?? THANKS!

Comment: I would prefer not to use Perl, but that looks like it would work.  But be wary of newline conversions in the ttf file--I don't know enough about ttf to know if that's an issue.  Also, I wouldn't tell people the reason they can't get to the font--that tells them how they can trick the site into letting them in.

Comment: @robert: If you go on the page that includes the font and paste the URL in the addressbar, you can afaik download it, even without spoofing the referer.

Comment: @thejh browsers only send the Referer field when you click a link or submit a form. If you type something in the address bar, the current site isn't "referring" you to the next one, so that field is not sent.

Comment: Wait, I'm lost. When my browser loads a .CSS file for my website, the referer for that file is the website that contains it?

Comment: @fedeisas my bad--automated .css, .js and image requests contain the Referer field as well

Answer (score 0):

Render the text on the server.

Comment: how would you go about doing this ? render it on the server as an image  ?

Answer (score 0):

Heard of Cufon? http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

or typekit: http://typekit.com/

or SFIR: http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/

I hope these help you with your research.

Comment: Thanks for your input! TypeKit is great, I take their mechanism for inspiration (check the answer again, it's solved) but I wasn't going to pay! SIFR and Cufon were great a few months ago, but now I try not to use flash, @font-face rules!